# wsl2 Ubuntu error with my alias 's: invalid option -- '

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is my wsl2 Ubuntu 18.04 installation. What is wrong with my .bash_aliases file?

```
kevin@PROBOOK:~$ la
's: invalid option -- '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
kevin@PROBOOK:~$ type la
'a is aliased to `ls -Ahl
kevin@PROBOOK:~$ cat .bash_aliases
alias la='ls -Ahl'
alias lh='ls -hl'
alias ping='ping -c 3'
DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
```

Comment: What does `cat -A .bash_aliases` say? did you edit the file in Windows by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as @steeldriver is implying,  was that I edited the .bash_aliases file from windows with CRLF line endings.

Once I changed it to LF, everything worked as expected